# Hundreds of Running / Terminated threads a minute

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 and Npgsql 2.2.5.0 to connect from an ASP.NET web service written with VB.NET to the PostgreSQL server.

The webservice gets around 15 requests a second.

The connection string I use is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PostgreConnectionStringPCMRead" 
               connectionString="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=5432;User  
               Id=the_user;Password=the_password;Database=example;
               CommandTimeout=600;Timeout=30;ConnectionLifeTime=30;
               Pooling=False;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I take a look at the Windows Resource Monitor, I see hundreds of Terminated connections.

[image]

I realise that I am using Pooling=False, however when I set Pooling=True, I get errors "Timeout while getting a connection from pool."

With every query I use the following Class (I've left in only the essential code):

```
Public Class dlNpgSQL
    Dim _sqlCommand As NpgsqlCommand
    Dim _sqlDataAdapter As NpgsqlDataAdapter
    Dim _dataset As DataSet

    Public Sub New()
        _sqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.                      
                         ConnectionStrings("connstring").ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDataSet(ByVal strQuery As String) As DataSet
        _dataset = New DataSet
        _sqlDataAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(strQuery, OpenConnection)
        _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataset)
        Return _dataset
    End Function

    Public Function OpenConnection() As NpgsqlConnection
        If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
           _sqlConnection.Open()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub CloseConnection()
       If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            _sqlConnection.Close()
       End If
    End Function
End Class
```

And then the actual query:

```
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim objDBRead As New dlNpgSQL("connstring")
tmpSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1"
ds = objDBRead.GetDataSet(tmpSQL)
If (objDBRead IsNot Nothing) Then
    objDBRead.CloseConnection()
End If
```

So obviously, I'm opening and closing the connection with each query.

Is this the correct way to do things?

Should I be using pooling, and if yes, why am I getting the errors and how can I fix the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you'd need a bigger `Maximum Pool Size`, though that is questionable with the as few transactions as you seem to have, unless they run for a long time.

Comment: I've set the Maximum Pool Size to 100. I have some long running queries, ~3 seconds which account for about 30% of the queries. I should clarify, there are 15 requests a second for the webservice, each request generates 5 queries.

Comment: If my skills at algebra do not desert me, the long runners should account for about 15 of your connections then,  so not dangerous. Perhaps you should turn on logging on the PostgreSQL server to see what's going on.

Comment: It seems that your algebraic skills are still sharp :) In the log files I only have the long running queries. I've set the logging options: client_min_messages = warning and log_min_messages = warning. The only reason I can come up with for the 100% CPU usage is the connector. This is on the "read" server. The CPU on the "write" is minimal. Any time I check the running queries (pg_stat_activity) I see about 10 of these queries are running.

Comment: You must get the pool running. Try setting `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 to see all statements in the log.

Comment: As mentioned above, unless you are using some external pooling (like pgbouncer), you definitely must turn on pooling. If you're getting a timeout, investigate that rather than just turning of pooling. You may need to tweak the pool's parameters (see [the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) for more info).

Comment: Also, much more importantly - is there any reason for using such as ancient Npgsql version (2.2.5)? Unless you have one, upgrade to 3.2.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, I'm using Pooling now on 3.2.5. I wrote a Windows application to test it and I saw that the postgres.exe process wasn't opening and terminating as it did without pooling. However, on my webservice, I'm getting hundreds of terminated processes a minute.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I'm using pooling but I keep getting an error message that the pool is exhausted. I increased the pool size to 1024, which didn't stop the error. I changed the Connection Idle Lifetime to 60 and it also didn't stop the message. When the pool is exhausted, why doesn't a new pool get used? In the Performance Monitor, I see the NumberOfPooledConnection growing and growing.

Comment: Maybe you do not return connections to the pool correctly when you are done. Are all these connections `idle` in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: No. 4 idle and 3 active. Could it be that I've missed a closeconnection somewhere in the code? Perhaps when the pooling is off, after the webservice has finished the function, it closes and therefore terminates the postgres.exe instance on the server.

Comment: But if that were the case, wouldn't there be a lot of idle connections in pg_stat_activity?